# TeamCity Tests tab doesn't show up in TeamCity 8.0

Tags: php, unit-testing, continuous-integration, phpunit, teamcity

I have TeamCity Professional 8.0.2. I set up PHPUnit and Build run succesfully. My problem is the Tests tab doesn't showed up so I can not see what was the tests result.I followed these instructions: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/01/continuous-integration-for-php-using-teamcity/

And this is the Build log. if it helps in solution:

```
[09:32:46]Checking for changes
[09:32:54]Publishing internal    artifacts [09:32:54][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending    build.start.properties.gz file
[09:32:54]Clearing temporary directory: C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[09:32:54]Checkout directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\da454545e33b4979
[09:32:54]Updating sources: server side checkout (11s)
[09:32:54][Updating sources] Building incremental patch for VCS root: svn: https://riouxsvn.com/svn/teamcityphp
[09:33:05][Updating sources] Repository sources transferred
[09:33:05][Updating sources] Updating C:\BuildAgent\work\da454545e33b4979
[09:33:05]Step 1/1: Run tests with coverage (Command Line)
[09:33:05][Step 1/1] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script6386721482072578369.cmd
[09:33:05][Step 1/1] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\da454545e33b4979
[09:33:06][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 0
[09:33:06]Publishing internal artifacts
[09:33:06][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[09:33:06]Publishing artifacts
[09:33:06][Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [build/release/*7*, unitTests/codeCoverage => coverage.zip]
[09:33:06][Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path 'build/release/*7*' not found
[09:33:06][Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path 'unitTests/codeCoverage' not found
[09:33:06]Build finished
```

Comment: That question is probably better asked at http://www.jetbrains.com/support/teamcity/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity command line runner is a tool to run arbitrary commands, and so it does not track test excution.

To collect test results, you should add Build Feature: [XML Report Processing](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/XML+Report+Processing). Just tell it you have Ant JUnit reports, and point it to proper directory (where PHPUnit stores the results)